# Longer URLs no longer work

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

Until recently, a [complex query](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog%20or%20iso-prolog%20or%20dcg%20or%20constraint-programming%20or%20logic-programming%20or%20yap%20or%20tau-prolog%20or%20swi-prolog%20or%20sicstus-prolog%20or%20gnu-prolog%20or%20x-prolog%20or%20b-prolog%20or%20xsb%20or%20clpfd%20or%20successor-arithmetics%20or%20prolog-cut%20or%20prolog-dif%20or%20failure-slice%20or%20prolog-toplevel%20or%20answer-set-programming%20or%20theorem-proving) was possible. But now, I get as response Bad Request - Invalid URL. When I [shorten the query](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog%20or%20iso-prolog%20or%20dcg%20or%20constraint-programming%20or%20logic-programming%20or%20yap%20or%20tau-prolog%20or%20swi-prolog%20or%20sicstus-prolog%20or%20gnu-prolog%20or%20x-prolog%20or%20b-prolog%20or%20xsb%20or%20clpfd%20or%20successor-arithmetics%20or%20prolog-cut%20or%20prolog-dif%20or%20failure-slice) it still works.

More specifically
this [long query](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/t12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890) doesn't work on SO, but without the last character [it does work](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/t1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789). And here on MSO an [even longer query](/tags/t12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890) works.

Is this an intended change?

See [also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367449/using-a-custom-filter-with-a-lot-of-tags-throws-an-error-on-refreshing-the-page).

Comment: All of those links work for me? (Although those searches do break the UI a bit)

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: Tags are limited to 35 characters, so the queries in the second paragraph are ridiculous.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: "doesn't work" means as described in *now, I get as response Bad Request - Invalid URL.*

Comment: What browser/OS? All of them work on MS Edge 93 on Windows 10.

Comment: FWIW, those long ones also don't work for me. (Also bad request.)

Comment: I posted a similar bug on MSE: [Using a custom filter with a lot of tags throws an error on refreshing the page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367449) - some people also reported that the longer URLs worked for them. Not sure why.

Comment: There is a workaround, sort of. Make that into a custom filter and *only click the custom filter*. Visiting the link with the long query in it or even refreshing the page doesn't work.

Comment: Repro, FF90: *"Bad Request - Invalid URL HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid."*

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: CDN?

Comment: No repro on Firefox Nightly 92.0a1.

Comment: Debugging into the Network panel, I see a 400 bad request on a request for https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-pC0fvYGno20/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAnnY7rlafwqYFJ3orqxyM-7S3KIbuNTUA/mo/photo.jpg?sz=32, but that's someone's gravatar or something. I also use Do Not Track and "Strict Tracking Prevention" as well as a Pihole device to block ads. I can't reproduce this in Firefox 90 or Chrome 91.

Comment: The length after `...tags/` is 395 characters (URL total 426).

Comment: This also affects the API, apparently. I get the same error if the URL is long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, the original query works again! Thank you.

Comment: You might have been saved by a slightly different issue: https://stackapps.com/a/9040